# Array data from Graphql is not populating a component in React

Tags: reactjs, database, graph, server-side-rendering

I am trying to render multiple checkboxes that have two functions:

1. Show two states: checked and unchecked
2. Update a checked array with the checked checkboxes

Currently, I am successfully able to accomplish these two goals with dummy data:

```js
const dummyPlayers = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Puppa' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Korvo' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Jesse' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Terry' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Gobblins' }
  ]
```

This is the shape of the array I want to populate the checkboxes with:

```js
[
    {
        "id": "936d6050-00df-4bd4-bc54-6ce58ad0210c",
        "name": "Travis",
        "owner": "moralesfam",
        "type": "Member",
        "createdAt": "2021-09-24T20:08:02.292Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-24T20:08:02.292Z"
    }...
]
```

However, when I start pulling data in from a database with Graphql, while I am able to render the checkboxes to the DOM, they are not interactive (don't show checked state) and don't log the checked checkboxes.

I bring in the data, an array of objects through a custom React hook, called useMembers and the data is stored in a members array. Console logging members prints out the array, but as soon as I swap the dummyPlayers for the members array, the two goals I stated earlier are unsuccessful.

```js
// RecordGame.js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import useLoadMembers from '../hooks/useLoadMembers'
import useUser from '../hooks/useUser'


function RecordGame() {
  const dummyPlayers = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Puppa' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Korvo' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Jesse' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Terry' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Gobblins' },
  ]

  const { members } = useLoadMembers(updateLoading)
  const { user } = useUser()

  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    new Array(members.length).fill(false)
  )


  let playingPlayers = []
  for (var index in checkedState) {
    if (checkedState[index] === true) {
      playingPlayers.push(dummyPlayers[index])
    }
  }

  console.log(playingPlayers)

  const handleOnChange = (position) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((player, index) =>
      index === position ? !player : player
    )
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState)
  }

  // Rendered elements
  const playerCheckboxes = dummyPlayers.map((player, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <label htmlFor={player.name}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id={player.name}
            name={player.name}
            checked={checkedState[index]}
            onChange={() => handleOnChange(index)}
          />
          <span> {player.name}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  })

  return (
        <div>
          <form>
            {/* Game Players */}
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="players">
                Who Played?
              </label>
              <div>{playerCheckboxes}</div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      )}
    </Dashboard>
  )
}

export default RecordGame
```

```js
//useLoadMember.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { API, Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import { listMembers } from '../graphql/queries'

const useLoadMembers = (updateLoading) => {
  const [members, updateMembers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMembers()
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])

  const fetchMembers = async () => {
    try {
      let memberData = await API.graphql({
        query: listMembers,
        variables: { limit: 100 },
      })

      updateLoading(false)

      let allMembers = memberData.data.listMembers.items
      setFilteredMembers(allMembers)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }

  const setFilteredMembers = async (allMembers) => {
    const { username } = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    const myMemberData = allMembers.filter((p) => p.owner === username)

    updateMembers(myMemberData)
  }

  return { members }
}

export default useLoadMembers
```

In this first, picture, I used the dummyPlayers array and got the results I wanted.
[image]

However, in this second screenshot, I replaced the dummyData with the members array and did not get any results I wanted.

[image]

I'm just confused on why I am getting different results with the same array shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wherever you use `members` you will need to check that members is not undefined before it gets used. If the api calls are not complete, it will get set initially as undefined.

eg: `members && members.map(() => ....)`